# What is the purpose of closed brackets after return statement in `alert(( function(){return this}() ))`?

Tags: javascript, return, alert, brackets

I've been reading about the `this` keyword on MDN. [In their article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#In_an_in%E2%80%93line_event_handler) they have mentioned the following example:

```
<button onclick="alert((function(){return this}()));">
  Show inner this
</button>
```

- What is the purpose of brackets `()` after return statement `{return this}()`?

Comment: To actually call the anonymous function

Comment: Those brackets make the function a **self-invoking** anonymous function.

Comment: @ag_dhruv But it works even if we don't enclose the whole function and function call inside closed brackets, e.g. `( function(){return this}() )` works as well. The other post says enclosing function definition inside brackets  converts the function definition into an expression.